# Возведение в степень в C (power (b,n))

Tags: c, алгоритм

Спасибо за ответы на мой предыдущий вопрос, хоть до конца все же не понятно, как и в этом вопросе.

Читаю книгу "Язык программирования ANSI C" 2е издание (Б. Керниган, Д. Ритчи)
Раздел 1.7 - Функции, 1.8 - Аргументы: передача по значению

```
power(base,n)
int base, n;
{
  int i, p;
  p=1;
  for (i=1; i<=n; ++i)
    p=p*base;
  return p;
}
```

или вот еще

```
int power(int base, int n)
{
  int p;
  for (p=1; n>0; --n)
    p=p*base;
  return p;
}
```

непонятен код в {}, i - понятно, что итератор, а p - что это? Не могу понять как оно влияет на power (base,n)

Comment: P – переменная хранящая промежуточное значение. Base умножается на Р столько раз на сколько возводим в степень.

Comment: BTW, пример не очень :) Потому что при возведении в степень инта и накоплении результата в инте же легко словить переполнение.

Comment: И вообще надо понимать что возведение в степень методом последовательного умножения идея так себе :) Или переполнение будет или бешеной размерности цикл. А если надо отрицательную степень? Но для примера в книжке - нормально

Comment: В академических терминах, `p` это то, что называется *аккумулятор* или *накопитель*. Паттерн накопления выглядит так: на входе имеем начальное значение, коллекцию значений и некую двуместную операцию (сложение, умножение, конкатенация, и пр.). Помещаем в аккумулятор начальное значение, и затем на каждом шаге итерации применяем операцию к аккумулятору и очередному значению из коллекции, сохраняя результат снова в аккумулятор.

В конце цикла аккумулятор содержит требуемое значение: число. возвёдённое в положительную степень, факториал положительного числа и т.д.

Comment: Если интересно [вот](http://algolist.manual.ru/maths/count_fast/fast_exp.php) например алгоритмы быстрого возведения в степень.

Comment: всем спасибо, я понял - p {} - сам процесс возведения в степень, и понял каким образом. Когда n станет 0, процесс возведения в степень прекратится. Получили результат хранящийся в p, НО как p попадает в power(base,n) (кода который перенимает значение p в base не видел). 
ааа, все я понял, это и не нужно, результат = p!
Осталось просто prinf(p)!